# Listview vs datagrid

Tags: .net, wpf, listview, gridview, datagrid

What are the main advantages of using a datagrid control over using a listview? When should each one be used?

Answer (score 15):

Some points to consider that [Colin Eber](http://www.codeplex.com/site/users/view/ColinEber) have stated in [DataGrid vs GridView](http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/40802?ProjectName=wpf) discussion:

> - ListView (GridView) is a readonly control out-of-the-box.The standard solution would be to synchronise the list with a 'details view' comprised of textBoxes
> - The DataGrid allows in-place editing of data
> - The DataGrid performs transaction edits (the row is treated as an atom)
> - The DataGrid support auto-column generation
> - The DataGrid has a RowDetails element (if you like that sort of thing!)
> - The DatGrid supports pretty much everything the ListView does, multiple selection modes, styling, etc ...

And another important one:

- The DataGrid has build-in sorting support by clicking on column header. While add sorting to ListView/GridView is [absolutely possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994148/best-way-to-make-wpf-listview-gridview-sort-on-column-header-clicking), I'd rather prefer to have such kind of things out-of-the-box in DataGrid.

Comment: what about performance? a Datagrid with 200 items (8 columns) grouped by one columns needs 20s + on my machine to render.

Comment: @Firo: That' definitelly not a problem of DataGrid. The performance bottleneck must be somewhere else.

Comment: @Liero i exchanged the datagrid with the wpf toolkit datagrid and the problem went away. It is definitly a problem with the plain wpf datagrid. I tested that It takes ages to measure with the groupings

Comment: I was not aware of this performance issue, however it seems to be fixed in WPF4.5+

Answer (score 11):

I've abandoned the ListView for the DataGrid in .Net 4, since templating the columns is easier.

Layout is also more sensible, and I don't need to remember to set the HorizontalContentAlignment to Stretch to get the cell contents to cover the cell. Another nice bit of functionality is edit templates on the DataGrid, which relieves me of having to use a CellTemplateSelector to get a different control when editing the cell.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Are there any differences with events for data changes in columns, ease of sorting / filtering data or is it all much the same?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, since I use binding to a model in order to sort, filter and get data update notifications. But for that, ListView and DataGrid appear similar.

Comment: My current application has database > Entity Framework > Observable collection (in viewmodel) > listview.  What's important for me is that I would like to have the data in the datagrid update when the database data changes. Not sure how simple that is to do but looking into it right now.