# Difference between ListView and DataGrid in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, listview, gridview, datagrid

I have to retrieve some questions from the database and display them on the user screen dynamically. I also need to add some controls in the columns of grid view, basically a question and input box for an answer.

Please suggest which one should I use? `ListView` or `DataGrid`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listview vs datagrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174428/listview-vs-datagrid)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Well, in WPF the difference between `ListView` and `DataGrid` is just one. Editing. You need editing use `DataGrid`, otherwise use `ListView`. You can edit in `ListView` also but it is easier and build in `DataGrid`. Otherwise, whatever can be displayed in `DataGrid`, can be displayed in `ListView`.

One thing which `DataGrid` supports and `ListView` doesn't (out of the box) is automatic column generation.

You can read [this article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx) for a better understanding of `DataGrid` and also about the major differences between `ListView` and `DataGrid`.

Comment: There are definitelly more differences. One of them is column sizing. In datagrid you can stretch column to fill grid size, in listview you can't. As far as I know, ListView was introduced in WPF 3.5 but was later replaced by DataGrid, but its still present for compatibility reasons

Comment: And column sorting.

Comment: Worth noting that editing in `DataGrid` can be turned off using `IsReadOnly="True"`

Comment: Anyone know which is faster when using virtual mode for a large amount of rows?

Comment: ListView not supports percent column width.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not a WPF expert, but it terms of just the controls themselves.

When thinking of ListView think Windows Explorer, the pane where you see all you're files, thats a ListView.

When thinking data base its **usually** (I said usually) a data grid, mouse over the **gridview** tag and read the description.

Some very obvious reasons why you would want a gridview is its directly editable. You can have your user enter the questions and the answer in there. Note, since ListViewItem is an Content Control  you also could customize it easily like [this article does](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WPFListView09092008224322PM/WPFListView.aspx).

Also see if this [GridView tutorial](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/fc9a5bf6-f5bb-4443-a92a-c9a46fd3aeb2/wpf-gridview-sample-to-in.aspx) helps.

You haven't given much of the description of how you need the UI, but you could play around and do anything you like.

You could even make a User Control for a [Question + Input box for Answer]. Then you could use a StackPanel (or even a listview) to list them out.

Hope that helped.