# WPF ListView vs DataGrid Performance

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am currently only using `ListView`s in WPF to display data that does not need to be edited. But I don't really like the style of the `ListView` and it seems to be missing some functionality like letting a `GridViewColumn` fill the remaining space. So I was wondering what the performance impact would be if I start using non-editable `DataGrid`s.

Is there a large performance difference if any between the two?

Comment: From [Eric Lippert](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) **If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses.**

Comment: I'll put my money on the black one !!

Comment: @SonerGönül what tools can I use to measure the performance? As I would not be able to determine which was fastest myself and changing all of my `ListView`s to `DataGrid` seems a bit impractical. Sorry I have never done performance testing so I'm not sure what to use.

Comment: Finally, what did you use/do?

Answer (score 3):

`ListView` in WPF is a light-weight control : some functions provided by `DataGridView` are not available. See [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4766730/2463594) for further information. If you are not satisfied with the `ListView` functions then `DataGridView` is the other choice to solve your problems.

Keep in mind that a `DataGridView` control will take some additional memory space on loading. However, the memory difference occupied by the `ListView` and `DataGridView` controls should not be large. This memory size can be seen by some memory profiling tools like the .Net memory profiler.

Some third party controls have memory leak issues which will hinder overall application performance, but all the controls in Microsoft libraries are performance and memory optimized.

With small amounts of data (<100 rows), you can't feel any performance difference between these controls. But if your application tries to display some big amount of data (>1000 rows) it may cause a delay of operations like scrolling: that's why the feature called `VirtualizationStackPanel` was implemented. Using it may resolve scrolling issues.