# Sorting the WPF Listview

Tags: wpf, listview, sorting, gridview

Iam having a ListView named **"ListLoginDetails"** in WPF. In which I displays two columns namely **"User_Name", "Password"** through DataSet. Now I haven to **Sort** the ListView on Both Ascending & Descending Order. Based upon the button clicked.....

Home.Xaml:

```
    <ListView Name="ListLoginDetails" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Table}" Margin="18,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="3" >
       <ListView.View>
          <GridView x:Name="gridView">
               <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="User_Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id}" />
               <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Password" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Password}" />
          </GridView>
       </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: View the Code, @michele

Comment: Since is a listview witha gridview inside, you can take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994148/best-way-to-make-wpf-listview-gridview-sort-on-column-header-clicking